# How to assign a shortcut key (something like Ctrl+F) to a text box in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0, keyboard-shortcuts, ctrl

I am building a tool using C#. It's a Windows application. I have one text box on a form, and I want to assign focus to that text box when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture the `KeyDown` event and place an if statement in it to check what keys were pressed.

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)) {
        txtSearch.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

One way is to override the ProcessCMDKey event.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do Something");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

EDIT: Alternatively you can use the keydown event - see *[How to capture shortcut keys in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839201)*.

Comment: I used to go for the alternative, but this is way simpler! +1

Answer (score 2):

1st thing Make sure that the Your Windows Form property is "KeyPreview=true"

2nd Thing Open Form Event Property And double click on "KeyDown"
And 
Write The Following code inside The Body of Event:-

```
private void form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if ((e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode ==Keys.S)) 
     {
           TextBox1.Focus();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event that catches a key press on the form, analyse the key press and see if it matches one of your shortcut keys and then assign focus.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to **assign an access key to a control with a label**. You assign a shortcut based on a label related to the textbox.

> **To assign an access key to a control with a label**
>
> 1. Draw the label first, and then draw the other control.
>
> -or-
>
> Draw the controls in any order and set the TabIndex property of the
> label to one less than the other control.
>
> 2. Set the label's UseMnemonic property to true.
> 3. Use an ampersand (&) in the label's Text property to assign the access key for the label. For more information, see Creating Access
>    Keys for Windows Forms Controls.
>
> Source :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-access-keys-with-windows-forms-label-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

In the picture below, if you press ALT+Y the focus moves to the textbox.

[image: Example]

Comment: Ok, just added more info.